# Authenticating through Azure Active Directory in a Web App

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-active-directory

I've been following [guide](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/aspnetcore2-2) on authenticating my web app through Azure Active Directory.

My task is just simply Displaying the user's Full name and/or Email after login with Azure Active directory.

I've been able to make it work locally and registering my app in https://apps.dev.microsoft.com. However, adapting everything to app service context breaks it.

Some questions pops in my mind. 
 1. What is the essence of the `Reply URL`?
 2. Should I reflect the `Reply URL` in the `appsettings.json`?

Comment: Reply Url is the Url to which AAD will send tokens to. This helps AAD not send tokens for your app to any where.
You can have multiple reply urls

Answer (score 2):

> What is the essence of the Reply URL?

In the case of a web API or web application, the `Reply URL` is the location to which Azure AD will send the authentication response, including a token if the authentication was successful. For the details, please read [here](https://medium.com/@marilee.turscak/reply-urls-vs-postlogoutredirecturis-in-azure-active-directory-aad-20f57a03267b).

> Should I reflect the Reply URL in the appsettings.json

For this guide, you do not need this in the `appsettings.json`. You just need to replace the values of `domain name,tenantid` and `clientid` in the `appsettings.json`.

.

Comment: If there is anything update, please let me know, thanks!

Comment: thanks i'll be giving it a shot for the whole day again.

Comment: If the answer is useful, please help mark it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> AADSTS50011: The reply url specified in the request does not match the reply urls configured for the application

For this error, it is caused by the mismatched `replyUrls` which is defined in the `Application Manifest`.

Follow steps below:

- Check your published App Service URL
- Login https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/
- Find the registered applications and Edit Application Manifest
- Modify the `homepage` and `replyUrls` with your app service URL.
- For `replyUrls`, it should be something like `[app service url]/signin-oidc`